# How is White winning in this OTB position?

Tags: learning, winning

Can anyone kindly guide me on how White has won in this picture of the end of an OTB game?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that despite the clock, it is Black to move? The thing is that he is going to lose his f-pawn and then white will get a queen.

Comment: Beside @RemcoGerlich vrey credible hypothesis (White played Kd5, Black held out his hand in sign of resignation before White even pressed the clock), the others possibilities I can imagine (i.e., if it is White's turn) is that Black lost on time, resigned by mistake... or that there is a White unit on a1, a2, b2 or a3, hidden by the player's hand !

Comment: because white has a queen on a2?  Whose move is it?

Answer (score 8):

In the picture, it could be either the two simply agreeing to the draw, or black resigning, depending on who has the move. Both are typically followed by a handshake.

White to move is a draw.

```
 [FEN "8/3k4/5p2/3K1P1p/7P/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

 1. Kc5 {The only move} Kc7 {Again the only move.} 2. Kd5 Kd7= {Both sides are forced to repeat here, and it is a draw.}
```

Now, black to move loses as black has to cede space, and then material.

```
 [FEN "8/3k4/5p2/3K1P1p/7P/8/8/8 b - - 0 1"]

 1... Ke7 2. Kc6 Ke8 3. Kd6 Kf7 4. Kd7 Kf8 5. Ke6 Kg7 6. Ke7 Kg8 7. Kxf6 Kf8 8. Kg5 Kf7 9. Kxh5 Kf6 10. Kg4 $18
```

Comment: the pawns are on f5 and f6, not f6 and f7 :)

Comment: Oops, thanks Hamish. I will look again, and edit as necessary. That must be why Rewan deleted his answer, and I saw the positions there, and was swayed.

Comment: No sense in even bothering to capture the other pawn — after 8. Kg6 Kg8 (8... Ke8 9. Kg7) 9. f6, Black gets their pick of poisons with 9... Kf8 10. f7 Ke7 11. Kg7 or 9... Kh8 10. Ke7 and 11. f7. In either case, the pawn queens next move.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Of course, but for someone asking that question, the Kh8 line is much more complicated than just taking the second pawn, and having a tempo in reserve to avoid any stalemates, if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's black to move this is a very simple win. White has the opposition and a strong king position. I would recommend reading up on the opposition. White can effectively "push" the black king back because black has no alternative. A decent endgame player will see this as a win almost instantly.